# incompatible types at argument #1

Tags: c

I have few basis on C language but I'm a beginner in development.

I have to integrate this code :

```
    `//IoHwab_fls.h
    ...
    Std_ReturnType ReturnVal;
    Fls_AddressType Test_ProgData[2 * FLS_PAGESIZE];
    uint8* Test_ReadData[2 * FLS_PAGESIZE];
    ...
```

and

```
//IoHwab_fls.c

#include "IoHwab_fls.h"

void flsDemo(void)
{
    ...
    ReturnVal = Fls_17_Pmu_Erase( FLS_BANK0_LINEAR,FLS_BANK_SIZE);
    ...
    ReturnVal = Fls_17_Pmu_Write(Test_ProgData, FLS_BANK0_LINEAR,(2*FLS_PAGESIZE));
    ...
    ReturnVal = Fls_17_Pmu_Read(FLS_BANK0_LINEAR ,Test_ReadData,(2 * FLS_PAGESIZE));
    ...
}
```

in a more wider project. However I'm in front of the following error :

```
IoHwab_fls.c 23/31 incompatible types at argument #1
```

So here is the `Fls_17_Pmu_Write(...)` and `Fls_17_Pmu_Read(...)` prototypes :

```
extern Std_ReturnType Fls_17_Pmu_Write( Fls_AddressType TargetAddress,
                             const uint8 *SourceAddressPtr,
                             Fls_LengthType Length
                           );

extern Std_ReturnType Fls_17_Pmu_Read( Fls_AddressType SourceAddress,
                            uint8 *TargetAddressPtr, 
                            Fls_LengthType Length
                           );
```

and also the `Fls_AddressType` type declaration :

```
typedef uint32 Fls_AddressType;
```

I believe to have well defined the type of my first argument ? Is it ? Have you any idea of how I can solve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is of type `Fls_AddressType TargetAddress`, yet you pass in `Test_ProgData` which is **an array of `Fls_AddressType`**, and decays to a **pointer to the first element of the array**, hence the error is that your function requires `Fls_AddressType TargetAddress`, yet you're passing in `Fls_AddressType *`.

As for *how* you can solve this - well, I have no idea as I do not know what the program is *supposed to do*.

Comment: And in line 31 the OP passes uint8** instead of uint8* for the same reason.

Comment: Just modify it as you suggest :
ReturnVal = Fls_17_Pmu_Write(*Test_ProgData, FLS_BANK0_LINEAR,(2*FLS_PAGESIZE));

 ReturnVal = Fls_17_Pmu_Read(FLS_BANK0_LINEAR ,*Test_ReadData,(2 * FLS_PAGESIZE));

And the error disappear so ty to you both :D

Answer (score 3):

`Test_ProgData` and `Test_ReadData` are declared as arrays.

```
 Fls_AddressType Test_ProgData[2 * FLS_PAGESIZE];
 uint8* Test_ReadData[2 * FLS_PAGESIZE];
```

The signatures of `Fls_17_Pmu_Write` and `Fls_17_Pmu_Read` show that they can only take single elements of the type `Test_ProgData`  and `Test_ReadData`.

You can solve this only by **defining** a single instance of `Fls_AddressType`  and of `uint8*` and passing them to the functions.

Something like:

```
 Fls_AddressType My_Test_ProgData;
 uint8* My_Test_ReadData = malloc(1); //as size of uint8 is 1
```